# Javascript Python-Postgres

Tags: javascript, python, html, postgresql-9.1

I'm building a public database of scientific data.

By now I have a postgres 9.1 database running on a machine, and I've been using psycopg2 to interact from python 2.7.

At the other hand, I'm working on a Boilerplate html interface.

The question is, how to build the interaction between the webpage and the python/postgres database?  which library should I use ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a web framework. Finding the right one is a hard choice and source of lots of discussions. Have a look at this list: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: thanks , I'll try Django this time